# AHK - Use a variable to retrieve array info

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to extract array info using a variable, it just comes up blank though.

If I hard code it, it will display the correct info.

[image]

```
ProfileList := {}

ProfileList.Insert("Dave", {Name:"Dave",Password:"Daves Password",Server:"Regina Server"})
ProfileList.Insert("Jim", {Name:"Jim",Password:"Jims Password",Server:"Saskatoon Server"})
em :=Dave
MsgBox, % "Here is the Password for Dave: " ProfileList[%em%].Password
     . "`nHere is the Password for Jim: " ProfileList["Jim"].Password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing legacy and expression syntax.

First lets take a look at where you try to define the variable `em`.
Looks like you're trying to store the string `Dave` in there.
If you were using legacy syntax `em = Dave`, you'd use the `=` operator to assign text to the variable, and the variable `em` would indeed hold the string `Dave`.
But you're using expression syntax `em := Dave` (as you should, it's not the first decade of the 2000s anymore). So you're assigning an expression to the variable `em`. And the expression you're assigning is `Dave`. `Dave`, as an expression, is expected to be a variable. So you're assigning the variable `Dave` to `em`. Such a variable doesn't exist though, so you're assigning nothing (empty) to `em`.
To assign a string to `em` in expression syntax, you want to do `em := "Dave"`.

And then to the second problem, again using legacy syntax in an expression.
`ProfileList[%em%].Password`
`%variable%` would be the legacy syntax way reference a variable, but since we are in expression, we want to just do `ProfileList[em].Password` to reference the variable.

Legacy syntax vs expression syntax can be confusing. This page from the docs may help you out a bit:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm

I would recommend trying to get into the habit of never using legacy syntax. Of course it'll work as well, but it's good practice to not use it. Maybe you'll one day want to be writing in AHK v2 and then there's no using legacy syntax.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was testing it out. But now that I have read your answer, I'm not sure,. I would be using `%A_UserName%`

Comment: What are you unsure about? `A_UserName` is a variable pretty much like any other one.

Comment: Oh ya, just thought I needed the % symbols `MsgBox, % "Here is the Password for Dave: " ProfileList[A_UserName].Password` works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around "Dave" and no percent-symbols. This works:

```
ProfileList := {}

ProfileList.Insert("Dave", {Name:"Dave",Password:"Daves Password",Server:"Regina Server"})
ProfileList.Insert("Jim", {Name:"Jim",Password:"Jims Password",Server:"Saskatoon Server"})
em :="Dave"
MsgBox, % "Here is the Password for Dave: " ProfileList[em].Password
     . "`nHere is the Password for Jim: " ProfileList["Jim"].Password
```